# How to use {{action}} in dynamically loaded element in Handlebars.js?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am new to Handlebars.js, ember.js and currently in learning phase.
I have created one table in which i am loading data dynamically.
Also, I have added two columns for edit and delete action in table dynamically.
Now, for each row there is one edit and one delete button available.
Here is the code for the edit button which I added in table dynamically,

```
<button type='button' id='modaledit' class='btn btn-primary btn-mini' {{action 'showmodal1'}}>Edit</button>
```

But when I click the Edit button nothing is happening, I have created response for `{{action 'showmodal1'}}` in controller but it is not executing.

When I tried to use jQuery's `.live()` function in the view (in `didInsertElement`), it is showing the following error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live'
```

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: can you post some more code, especially how your controller looks like? amd the name for your template where your buttons live?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know for what you wanted to use jQuery's `.live()` function, but here is a simple example of how the `action` fired from a view, correctly invokes the respective method in the corresponding controller: http://jsbin.com/ewenuj/2/edit

Hope it helps.

Comment: :I am not able to use {{action 'showmodal1'}} to pop up my modal window.So, i am using .live() in didInsertElement of view.{{action 'showmodal1'}} is not working on button if that button is created dynamically.

Comment: @user2625690, can you post more code on how you setup looks like, e.g. how you modal view is setup etc. it will be easier to help I guess